# Find the biggest point where $G$ is invertible.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $G(x, y) = ((x - 1)^2, y^4)$,
>
> (i) let $t = (7, -3)$. Find the greatest real num $L$ such that $G$ is invertible in the neighborhood $\sqrt{(x - 7)^2 + (y + 3)^2} < L$.

I am aware of the inverse function theorem and I see that

$G$ is **invertible everything** except where if $t = (x, y)$, we cannot have either $x = 0$ or $y = 1$, but how can I further proceed with this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right (though you have them backwards) that you cannot have $x=1$ or $y=0$.  You are now asked what is the largest ball around $(7,-3)$ that does not include any points with $x=1$ or $y=0$.  $L$ should be the shortest distance from $(7,-3)$ to either of those planes.

Comment: I am a bit confused, I can got a bunch of equations by subtituting $x=1, y=0$ but I am unable to move forward. Mind giving another hint? For instance I have $36 + ( y + 3)^2 < R^2$

Comment: bump, would appreciate a small hint, great problem.

Comment: The shortest distance from a point to a plane is the line from the point which is perpendicular to the plane.  How far is it from $(7,-3)$ to the plane $x=1?$

Comment: The plane has equation $x + 0y = 1$, therefoe by the point-plane formula I got $7/\sqrt{1}$?

Comment: Edit, sorry about that. I used the formula and got $6$? So is $L = 6$?

Comment: It is a line, not a plane, because we are in $\Bbb R^2$, but that doesn't change things.  Yes, that distance is $6$, but what about in $y$?  You can just draw the lines $x=1$ and $y=0$, plot the point $(7,-3)$ and find the largest circle you can draw around $(7,-3)$ without hitting either line.

Comment: You mean $y = 0$? In this case, $$\frac{|-3|}{1} = 3$$? so I am assuming then $L = \min(L_1, L_2) = \min(6, 3) = 3$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: very interesting. I'm curios as to how your thinking went this way. I see that the circle must not entail the $x = 1, y = 0$ but how did that lead you to think about min distance to the planes?